# Salting passwords with client-side hash

Tags: security, hash, passwords, client-side, salt

Given that you really have to perform your password hashing on the client side, how can you implement server-side salting?

The first solution that I can think of is to ask for the user's salt from the server's users table before you perform the hash. But that means you're confirming that the user "exists" since you give him the valid salt of the user.

I've also thought that instead of storing the salt in the user's table, you can make the salt something that is available to the user, for example, a variation of his username. But consistency problems might arise because the server and the client needs to remember how exactly the salt is gotten from the provided user data.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Who said you have to perform the hashing on the client side? I always do it server side.

Comment: @Justin Sometimes client-side hashing is useful especially if you don't want the server to have any access to the the clear-text passwords. I know that hashing in the client side doesn't solve the security issues that hashing tends to solve, but in some cases, it could be handy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert with regards to the topic but how about using something like a one-time salt along with the solutions you mentioned.

Meaning, you provide the client a salting function that generates a salt based on a random seed for a short time frame. The seed itself is dynamic and changes after some time and must be the same between the server and client. After all, the salt need not be secret.

On the client side generate the salt using the username (or whatever user data is available) assuming it is unique. Then you generate the hash on the concatenated password and salt and send it on the server.

On the server side, you calculate the salt using the same salting function in the client with the username as the input. You then generate the hash just the same and determine if the two values match. You just have to make sure the time window is wide enough to allow successful authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing client-side is useful if you don't have HTTPS for logins, but it can have some disadvantages such as revealing your hashing and/or salting methods. That being said, if they have access to your password hash database, they probably already have access to that information.

In order to do only a server side salt, you will need to rehash the password using the salt and password hash. In this scenario you would store only the username, salt (if not using a username and password hash salt) and second hash.

If as from your example you wish to perform the salting on both client and server, I would suggest using a combination of username and the initial password hash to salt. The salt won't be unknown by the client as anyone could check your salting method and even apply it to a password cracker, but it will avoid them using a rainbow table to crack same password users.

Don't use the username by itself as a salt. If its a common username (eg. admin), then there is probably a table out there already with this salt.

The problem with using nyde1319's answer (sorry didn't have rights to comment on the answer) is that you will need to have an unencrypted version of the password in your database to perform the password+salt hash. Defeating the purpose of the hash. If it was done using a hashed version of the password, you'd have to store the first hash and they could just crack that hash, defeating the purpose of the salt.